# How to add event listeners for elements in slots (Vue.js)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to make a "characters-counter" vue component, that can count the number of input element's characters, like this:

```
<characters-counter v-slot="{charactersCount}">
    <div>{{ charactersCount }} Chars</div>
    <input type="text">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <input type="text">
</characters-counter>
```

I know I could do something like this:

```
<template>
    <div @keyup="changeCharactersCount" class="container">
        <slot :item="charactersCount"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

But I don't want to add an additional "container" element there.
So anyone knows how could I achieve the same purpose without the "container" element? That is, how to add the event listeners for the elements itself inside the slots?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just bind your `<input />` to a `v-model`?

Then where you want to get the count simply call a computed to get the count... So you would end up with something like this:

```
<characters-counter v-slot="{charactersCount}">
    <div>{{ getCharacterCount }} Chars</div>
    <input v-model="myInput" type="text">
</characters-counter>
```

Then your `data()` and `computed`:

```
data: (() => {
   myInput: '',
}),
computed: {
  getCharacterCount() {
    return this.myInput.length;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to bother the input elements inside the component. I want a component that can be used as simple as possible, it's the component's responsibility to bind the event of its children input elements.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could pass the event listener from the custom component to its slot content as a slot prop (like you're already doing with `characterCount`):

```html
<template>
  <label for="mySlot">My Custom Input</label>
  <slot id="mySlot"
    :characterCount="characterCount"
    :onCountCharacters="onCountCharacters">
  </slot>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const characterCount = ref(0)
    return {
      characterCount,
      onCountCharacters: e => characterCount.value = e.target.value.length
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Then the consumer would use the event listener on its `input`:

```html
<template>
  <characters-counter v-slot='{ characterCount, onCountCharacters }'>
    <input @keyup='onCountCharacters' placeholder='My Custom Input'>
    <span>{{ characterCount }}</span>
  </characters-counter>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-event-listeners-to-slot-content-typ8q?file=/src/components/CharactersCounter.vue)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to bother the input elements inside the component. I want a component that can be used as simple as possible, it's the component's responsibility to bind the event of its children input elements.